# How to work with database in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I am a PHP web developer. Now I want to work with ASP.NET but it's very difficult for me to work with databases in ASP.NET. I need some source link from where I can easily learn ASP.NET.

Comment: first u need to decide MVC or Webforms. nd then google it

Comment: Go for http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_linq.htm

Comment: The ASP.NET site has a **lot** of tutorials, walkthroughs, examples. The Microsoft Virtual Academy has a **lot** of courses and videos. Have you tried looking for any tutorials or courses before posting?

Comment: yes but all the tutorials are advanced level

Comment: Then use Google. Search as Introduction to ASP.Net

Answer (score 0):

A good start is the homepage of ASP.NET:
http://www.asp.net/.
It includes a [section](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) on how to work with Entity Framework which is an object relation mapper for SQL Server databases.

For WebForms there's a nice tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the template for asking questions.

Since you have asked , ASP.NET has flexible options of connecting/working with databases or you can write code using ADO.NET classes as well. I believe below links will provide a better understanding of working with databases in asp.net.

[w3schools - ASP.NET working with database](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_database.asp)

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178371(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you search you will find lot of sources over the web,but i recommend you to start with some basic topics , below are some topics with which you should start with :

- .Net Framework basics
- ASP.Net Page life Cycle
- Viewstate
- Data Controls
- ADO.Net
- Basic CRUD Operations on ASP.net Pages(CRUD =
  Create,Retrieve,Update,Delete)
- Caching in Asp.net
- Cookies Management

in Addition C# & VB are most often used languages with .Net Framework , you Can start with C# basics.

below is the link that will give you basic walkthrough
[Basic ASP.NET Walkthroughs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907589(v=vs.90).aspx)